# What is the best way to find a fixed number of RANDOM users in DB based on a parameter?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a Spring Boot REST API in Kotlin. The underlying db is Postgresql and I am using Spring Data JPA for database access.

I have a table called "Users" , where I have some user data. One of the user properties is "gender". It can have one of two values: MALE or FEMALE.

I would like to have a feature in my app to find a random number (say 20 for example) of people of specified gender that I have not seen before. I mean - let's assume I have a table where I store the ids of users that I have already seen.

So now, what I want to do is basically get 20 random users from Users table, where gender is MALE and id is NOT IN [list of ids I have seen].

The randomness of the query initially led me to creating a native query of the kind:

```
SELECT *  FROM users WHERE gender = :gender ORDER BY random() LIMIT :number
```

However, I realized that it might be very inefficient, since the `order by random()` part will be sorting the entire table (or ~half of the table if I select one gender).

So my second idea was to take care of the randomness in the code. So I decided to make a db call to count the amount of users (to fetch the highest id), then generate some id values in the range from 0 to the highest, filter out the ones that I have seen and then fetch the users from DB by ids:

```
val numberOfUsersInDatabase = userRepository.count()
    val idsOfUsersVotedForBefore = voteService.findIdsOfUsersVotedFor(requestingUser.id!!)
    val excludedIds = idsOfUsersVotedForBefore.plus(requestingUser.id)

    val idsToFetch = random.longs(2*amountOfIds, 1L, numberOfUsersInDatabase)
            .boxed()
            .filter { num -> !excludedIds.contains(num) }
            .limit(amountOfIds)
            .collect(toSet())
   val randomUsers = userRepository.findUsersByIds(idsToFetch)
```

But in this case I have no way of knowing what the gender of the randomly selected user is, so there is no possibility for me to filter the results by gender before making the db call.

Can you please advice how to tackle this better?

Comment: Are the IDs sequential?

Comment: Yes, id is a Long type value generated with a sequence

Answer (score 2):

I'm not wholly familiar with Kotlin language but I'll write out the logic in Java and hope it translates well to you from there.

Your goal is to fetch 20 of a single gender, but you can't figure out what gender it is until you fetch it. Since we're already fetching 20 rows from the database, we can grab more as spares.

We can use a cumulative distribution for an optimal count of how many rows we realistically need, using this tool: https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

Assuming 50/50 gender breakdown, probability is 0.5. You can adjust this if your gender distribution is different for your needs. If the gender breakdown is not 50/50, you can create separate bucket fetches for each gender to get an appropriate level of success. We want at least 20 successful matches.

> With a sample size of 60, we get a **99.6%** probability that we will have 20 or more matches for the gender.

So we can fetch 60 instead of 20, filter for the first 20 of selected gender. If we don't reach 20 (on a 0.4% chance), then redraw another set of 20 to fill out our group. So 99% of the time, 60 row fetches, on a bad one, probably 80 row fetches. This does away with any use of RAND on the DB side which should be suitable for extra-large databases.

```
Set<Long> idsToFetch = random.longs(2*amountOfIds, 1L, numberOfUsersInDatabase)
            .boxed()
            .filter { num -> !excludedIds.contains(num) }
            .limit(amountOfIds * 3)
            .collect(toSet());

List<User> randomUsers = userRepository.findUsersByIds(idsToFetch);

List<User> selectedUsers = randomUsers
                            .stream()
                            .filter(e -> e.gender == selectedGender)
                            .limit(amountOfIds)
                            .collect(toList());


if(selectedUsers.length < amountOfIds) { 
    //redo or single fetch operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

select 100 thousand id in your condition.the data about several MB in memory.just shuffle it.then `select * from tables in(id1,id2...,id20)`

Comment: this will be inefficient on the DB side, since `ORDER BY RANDOM()` will always reorder the entire table, regardless of how many records I want to retrieve. Meaning that if there are 20 million records that match my criteria and I only want to retireve 1000, it will still start by sorting the 20 million entries

Comment: firstly not use random by DB.if you have 20 million,random 200 Partition by code.select all ids in one Partition .then random get 1000 ids in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do not generate ids, instead generate row indexes.

Then in a loop you can do this

```
select top 1 start at :randomBase *
from users where gender = :gender
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a materialized view with the query in your post. It can be scheduled to refresh at a schedule of your choosing (using cron job or perhaps other tools offered by Postgres)

Comment: Hmm, if I understand correctly, such an approach would cause that the user would always receive the same 20 users for as long as I do not refresh the view, since the view will be randomly sorted once every time the refreshing runs

Comment: Yes, the data will be same between refreshes. This solution will only work if your API request volume is low (ex. 1000 male customers every week to send marketing emails) It will not scale for a high volume API (ex. 1000 male customers every minute, to post ads on websites they visit)